# How expensive is c# Async and await

Tags: c#, webclient, async-await

recently was experimenting with async and await using c#. This is my code

```
private async void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

    var client = new WebClient();

    var sw =  Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var downloadStringTask = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com");

    textBox1.Text += "Downloading string async "+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    sw.Restart();

    await downloadStringTask;

    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Downloaded "+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    sw.Stop();
}
```

and this the output im getting in textbox1.text

```
Downloading string async 5698
Downloaded 666
```

this means only calling the `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` is taking around `5.6 Seconds` to execute where as actual downloading is taking `<1 second`. When the reason this method is to be used is to save Thread Resources.

If this is true is there any actual case where this method of WebClient class should be used?? Or im just thinking in totally incorrect terms?

Comment: Hm, measuring only one time may result in misleading numbers

Comment: @Patrick i was willing to use this later in my web application in which the the Controller is created everytime

Comment: It is not just the time taken in downloading the data but also the time in resolving the dns and the time required for first time download.

I would suggest that you should try making yet another call. It will yield a different result as this time, the dns is already resolved and cached as well as the page is also cached.

Comment: The title does not really match the question. Good question though.

Comment: Wait, what are you asking again? When the WebClient class should be used? Or the cost of async and await? Or if you're thinking incorrectly?

Comment: what im asking is that in this particular case is the cost of using async and await is justified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting about 300 msec the first time, 0 msec every time after that.  About what I'd expect.  There is always a chunk of overhead when you first use code.  At a minimum you are measuring the cost of getting the System.Net code getting loaded into your program and initialized.  WebClient appears to have some overhead as well, I'm for example seeing an exception getting caught and handled when it looks through the registry for a web proxy.  Basic stuff that needs to be done before something can be done asynchronously.

Still, 5.7 seconds is a very long time.  You ought to be looking at environmental stuff, other parts of your machine that want to get involved whenever you are doing something internetty.  Like that web proxy, it might be set to auto-configure and that takes time.  Or like your anti-malware software or firewall getting excited about you starting to use an outbound IP address.  Etcetera, lots of moving parts involved with networking and it is never the same.

Comment: +1. .NET always does synchronous proxy autodetection (which may include a DNS request, downloading a proxy script, spinning up an AppDomain to compile the JavaScript into IL, and executing it) as well as (I think) DNS lookup. So if you have any proxy/DNS issues, the "asynchronous" HTTP methods are suddenly not so asynchronous. :(

Answer (score 2):

You are measuring the setup time. On my machine (and Internet connection), the first call produces:

```
Downloading string async 2636 // Varies wildly, can be up to 15s on some runs.
Downloaded 385
```

While the subsequent calls consistently produce:

```
Downloading string async 0
Downloaded 289 // With small variations.
```

Comment: ya this is what i encountered after several tries. but what exactly is SETUP TIME?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're measuring one-time setup costs, but as an alternative to 'running it more than once', you could just 'warm up' the particular web client.

For instance, between these 2 lines, add a (synchronous) Download* call

```
var client = new WebClient();

var sw =  Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

Perhaps something like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();

// different site, to help avoid pre-filling any caches involved
client.DownloadData("http://www.microsoft.com/");

var sw =  Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

Then your initial measuring won't include initial web client setup, and even your first run should have accurate timings (and should better match doing the same call multiple times, assuming HTTP 200 results each time, and not either served out of local cache or 304's)